# Python deal with date format like "1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th"

Tags: python, xml, minidom

I want to deal with those strings like:

```
"I will meet you at 1st."
"5th... OK, 5th?"
"today is 2nd\n"
"Aug.3rd"
```

To replace the "st|nd|rd|th" with other corresponsive string, actually are xml tags, I want to make those "1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th" into superscript looks:

```
1<Font Script=”super”>rd</Font>
5<Font Script=”super”>th</Font> ... OK, 5<Font Script=”super”>th</Font>?
```

Like this

Comment: What XML parser / object model are you using?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I am using the Python minidom, thanks for remind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use re module to identify the date patterns and replace them.

```
>>> re.sub(r"([0123]?[0-9])(st|th|nd|rd)",r"\1<sup>\2</sup>","Meet you on 5th")
'Meet you on 5<sup>th</sup>'
```

Regex **demo**: http://regexr.com/38lao

Comment: If this'll work depends *heavily* on the tools the OP is using; you cannot just insert the result of the regular expression into the tree and expect the `<sup>` text to become a tag (it'll be escaped instead).

Comment: But since OP does not tell us what XML parser he's using, I'd assume he's processing it as a raw string, and then it should work.

Comment: @MartijnPieters My answer provides the guidance to what needs to be done once OP has parsed the XML, this is what I infered from OPs question as there was no clear mention of XML parsing part in his description.

Comment: I'm just giving you a heads-up that this'll lead to inevitable follow-up questions.

Comment: @DhruvPathak thanks for your answer, I am using xml.dom.minidom for parsing.